# Add LIMIT and OFFSET to Raw Sql in Grails for pagination

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, grails, pagination

I have this raw sql that seems to be working. I want to add limit/offset to this query as I am doing a pagination. I am using oracle Xe and sql developer for database. I read that Limit keyword is not available in oracle and was wondering whats the best way to add limit/offset to this query.

```
final session = sessionFactory.currentSession;
final  String query  = "select distinct a.* from classification c join (select id from taxonomy_node "+ 
                                                        "start with id =:nodeId connect by nocycle prior id = parent_id) h " +
                                                        "on (c.node_id = h.id) join artifact a on (a.id = c.artifact_id) " +
                                                        "Where a.DOCUMENT_ID =:docid AND c.active=1 ";
final sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query);
artifacts = sqlQuery.with {
        addEntity(Artifact);
        setLong('nodeId',filterByAssociatedNodeId as Long);
        setLong('docid',document.id as Long);
        setFirstResult(startIndex);
        setMaxResults(limit);
        list();

}
```

there is something like setMaxResult but I dont think this will help me as I need an offset too. I am trying setFirstResult and setMaxResults for this.

Comment: You don't have ORDER BY. CONNECT BY retrieves rows in a certain order but it may be broken by the following join. If it doesn't matter which rows to show then you don't need offset.

Comment: may be add limit/offset to the list then ??

Comment: Limit and offset does exist in Oracle, from 12c. Just sewrch google for top-n oracle base, Tim Hall has a good demo in his site.

Comment: There are several ways to perform limit/offset, but I don't understand why you need offset if you retrieve unsorted list. Just use setMaxResult.

Comment: I am doing pagination So whenever the users click the next button it should return NEXT say 20 items . Thats why use offset for the start position of row may be  ?

Comment: OK. Then you definitely need ORDER BY. Otherwise a user may see the same rows on different pages

Comment: ok no problem Ill add order by some attribute but does limit/offset work on oracle sql ? how to frame  it ?

Comment: If you set setFirstResult and setMaxResults hibernate change your query and retrieve what you want. If there are some performance issues you may want to wirte you own query but I don't think it's your case

Comment: what about adding something like ORDER BY a.id OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY